# como implementar dropzone en un input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dropzone, dropzone.js

implementado dropzone exitosamente en un input file sirve bien , el problema viene que cuando le doy click a mi input para eleguir la imagen se detona dos veces mi input uno del dropzone y otro del input normal lo que quiero lograr es que no se detone dos veces y solo me salga una venta para eleguir mi imagen ya que se activa dos veces mi input , estava viendo otra forma de iniciar el drop zone pero no me logra funcionar alguien que sepa un metodo para que no se detone dos veces ese input , gracias por su atencion

```
 <section class="scroll-section" id="floatingLabel">
   
      <div class="card mb-5">
          <div class="card-body">

              <form id="formAddPerson" name="formAddPerson">
                  <!-- Single Image Uploader Start -->
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                      <section class="scroll-section" id="singleImageUpload">
                          <div class="position-relative d-inline-block" id="singleImageUploadExample">

                              <img id="imagenPrevisualizacion" src="img/profile/profile-11.webp" width="80" height="80" alt="alternate text" class="imgRedonda" />
                              <!-- <div id="foto-profile" class="upload">  -->

                              <button id="activarinput" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-icon-only btn-separator-light rounded-xl position-absolute e-0 b-0" type="button">
                                  <i data-acorn-icon="upload"></i>
                              </button>
                              <input name="inputGroupFile01" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-icon-only btn-separator-light rounded-xl position-absolute e-0 b-0" type="file" accept="image/*" id="inputGroupFile01" />
                          </div>



                      </section>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                      <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                      <label>First Name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                      <input required name="MiddleName" id="MiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" />
                      <label>Middle Name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                      <input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                      <label>Last Name</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-floating mb-3 w-100">
                      <input name="Title" id="Title" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                      <label>Title</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-floating mb-3 w-100">
                      <input name="Gender" id="Gender" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                      <label>Gender</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-floating mb-3 w-100">
                      <input name="IdBusinessEntity" id="IdBusinessEntity" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" />
                      <label>IdBusinessEntity</label>
                  </div>



              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" style="cursor: pointer" class="btn btn-primary" id="addEditConfirmButton" >Add</button>

           
          </div>
      </div>
    
</section>
```

y este es el de mi javascrip donde implemento el dropzone

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    
              $("#inputGroupFile01").dropzone({
      
            // The configuration we've talked about above
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            url:'FileUploader.ashx',

            // The setting up of the dropzone
            init: function () {
                var myDropzone = this;

                // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
                $("#addEditConfirmButton").on("click", function (e, formData) {
                    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                  
                    //myDropzone.processQueue();
                 

                    if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {


                        theFormModal.validate()
                        if (theFormModal.valid()) 
                        {
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
                            document.querySelector('#formAddPerson').reset();
                        }
                        else {
                            showWarning("Faltan campos");
                          
                        }

                        
                    }

                    else {
                        alert("eee");
                    
                               theFormModal.validate()

                                 if (theFormModal.valid()) {
                                     get("35A2BCF3-58F0-41B6-A845-46C53A53D0CE", {
                                    'FirstName': $("#FirstName").val(),
                                    'MiddleName': $("#MiddleName").val(),
                                    'LastName': $("#LastName").val(),
                                    'Gender': $("#Gender").val(),
                                    'Title': $("#Title").val(),
                                    'IdBusinessEntity': $("#IdBusinessEntity").val(),

                                     });
                                     window.location.reload();
                                   }

                              else {
                                  showWarning("Hay información restante, corrija e intente de nuevo.");
                                       }



                    }///////////////////////////fin del else

                  
                });

                // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
                // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
                this.on("sendingmultiple", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    theFormModal.validate()
                    if (theFormModal.valid()) {
                        formData.append('FirstName', $("input[name=FirstName]").val());
                        formData.append('MiddleName', $("input[name=MiddleName]").val());
                        formData.append('LastName', $("input[name=LastName]").val());
                        formData.append('Title', $("#Gender").val());
                        formData.append('Gender', $("#Title").val());
                        formData.append('IdBusinessEntity', $("input[name=IdBusinessEntity]").val());
                    }
                    else {
                        showWarning("Hay información restante, corrija e intente de nuevo.");
                    }
                });
                this.on("successmultiple", function (file, response) {
                    // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
                    // Redirect user or notify of success.
                    var imgName = response;
                /*file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");*/
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded :" + imgName);
                    showWarning("success");
                    window.location.reload();

                });
                this.on("errormultiple", function (file, response) {
                    // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
                    // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                

                });
            }

            /*}*/
        });
    
 });
```